# How can you make a texture not being affected by blender lights?

Tags: animation

I modelled a shampoo and I put a label texture onto front face of it. When I'm rendering it the label texture is darker which is obvious to me because blender lights affect it. How can you make a texture like this not being affected by lights and just be there with stable colors all the time(the same colors when I'm opening the texture as image)? Node screenshots would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Cycles then I would go for **Emission** shader with **IsCameraRay** linked to it **Strength**. This will make it act as shadeless flat material that doesn't receive shadows and doesnt emit lighting.[image]

Comment: works the same for image texture?

Comment: Yes, just plug the texture to the Colour of Emission